# Invert subsitution using regex and sed (unix tools)

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have a column of data of the form tt1234567 however some rows do not fill this criteria and I want to substitute this with a dash (-). Preferably this needs to be done only with unix tools.

at the moment I have sed -e 's/^(tt)/-'

But obviously that replaces everything starting with tt with dash, can i do the inverse command?

Comment: show the input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely you are looking for this:

```
sed '/^tt/!s/.*/-/' file
```

For example:

```
kent$  cat f
tt123456
;alsjf
tt123456

kent$  sed '/^tt/!s/.*/-/' f
tt123456
-
tt123456
```